# Update mysqli query with inner join

Tags: mysql

How to excute query and set done value = 1 if its 0  vice versa, I tried this code but doesn't work:

```
UPDATE orders set orders.done=1 inner 
JOIN mydate on orders.order_no=mydate.order_no and orders.date=mydate.order_date 
where done.orders=0
```

Comment: get rid of PHP and run your query in console/phpmyadmin and see what's wrong

Comment: please share table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE orders 
join mydate on orders.order_no=mydate.order_no and orders.date=mydate.order_date 
set orders.done=1
where order.orders=0
```